# Angular 8 SEO Images and Content on dynamic routes

Tags: angular, seo, search-engine, google-search

In my angular app, I have a few dynamic routes, like

`www.example.com/:username/profile`

`www.example.com/:device/details`

Basically when a profile page is loaded, i take the username from the url, and load a picture of the user from

`www.example.com/assets/users/:username.jpg`

or

`www.example.com/assets/devices/:device.jpg`

The users and the devices both change from time to time, can be done from an admin page.

I am already using Angular Universal for SSR, setting dynamic meta title and description for all my pages, setting the alts for all my images, so basically everything that I know of.

My question is:

If I have a user in my database with the username 'mike', how will the google crawler know, that there is a page  `www.example.com/mike/profile`, crawl that page, and if I search in Google for "Mike profile on example page", it will actually show that page in the search results, and in the Images, I will find Mikes profile picture.

How can I make this kind of dynamic routing SEO friendly?